# continuous time Markov chain, something the book does not explain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, proof-writing, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a problem with something in my book, under the chapter of continuous time Markov chains. I will post a link to what the book does. They do something which they seem to take for granted, but I do not think it is obvious. If what they do is is obvious, then the statement I have below must be obvious, but is it? If it is not, please help me prove it.

**statement:**

Assume that $T_1$ is exponentially distributed with paramenter $\lambda$. Every time the event happens it starts over again. And every time it happens, with probability p. The event is counted as a type 2 event.  Call the time between events to for $T_2$.

$\leftarrow \rightarrow$

$T_2$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda p$.

**Is this equivalence that obvious?** If not, how is it proved?

Here is why I have this question:

https://s28.postimg.org/gkslt0yst/question.png

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it obvious to you that the waiting time generated by this procedure will still be memoryless? The exponential distribution is the only continuous distribution that is memoryless. So we can completely characterize the waiting time by just computing it's mean.

$$\mu = \left(\frac{\nu_i}{\nu}\right)\frac{1}{\nu} + \left(1 - \frac{\nu_i}{\nu}\right)\left(\frac{\nu_i}{\nu}\right)\frac{2}{\nu} + \left(1 - \frac{\nu_i}{\nu}\right)^2\left(\frac{\nu_i}{\nu}\right)\frac{3}{\nu} + \ldots$$
$$ = \frac{\nu_i}{\nu^2} \left(1 + 2\left(1 - \frac{\nu_i}{\nu}\right) + 3\left(1 - \frac{\nu_i}{\nu}\right)^2 + \ldots\right)$$
$$ = \frac{\nu_i}{\nu^2} \left(\frac{1}{(1-\left(1 - \frac{\nu_i}{\nu}\right))^2}\right) = \frac{1}{\nu_i}$$

So the new procedure gives waiting times that are exponentially distributed with a rate given by $\nu_i$ exactly as required.

Comment: Hi,t hank youu that was very smart. I hope I can ask you another question. The only thing in the book that reminds me of what they did here was when we had a Poisson process, and we did sampling, then the new process would also be a poisson process with rate $\lambda p$. Here we do not have a Poisson process, but a general continous Markov chain, but can that result still be used here?

Comment: You mean that you had a Poisson process, but you would reject an event with probability $p$ leading to a rate $\lambda p$? Yes that's basically a similar argument.

Comment: Lets say you have a Poisson proess, and every time the event happens you characterize it by a type 2 event with probability p. Then the process only counting type two events will be a pisson process with rate $\lambda p$. In what I linked two in the book, we do not have a poisson process, but only a continuous time Markov chain, but we know that the waiting times here must be exponential with parameter $\nu_i$. So even though we do not have a Poisson process, can we still use the result above with sampling from the poisson process?

Comment: "You mean that you had a Poisson process, but you would reject an event with probability p leading to a rate λp? Yes that's basically a similar argument." I see but even though they are similar, can they be exactluy the same? That is that we can use that result directly here?

Comment: Well whatever argument was used to show the waiting time for type 2 events is exponential with rate $\lambda p$ can basically be used verbatim. It just so happens that in this case the rejection rate depends on the current state of the process; so that means that the post-sampling process with transition rates $\nu_i$ will no longer be Poisson. But the pre-sampling process is Poisson.

Comment: So essentially I'm saying that once you show that the one step waiting times are exponential with the right mean you know you have a continuous time markov chain (still markov since you're only using the current state to determin sampling rate) with the right transition rates. Those facts determine the process uniquely, so you know you have an alternative construction of realizations of the stochastic process you want

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! I did not understand all about the post and pre poisson sampling process. If you have time, and it is not too much work for you. Could you please show how to describe the process in terms of a Poisson process, and hence use the result from the Poisson process, and show that the answer is the same?

Comment: That's what the above argument does. You generate a Poisson process with rate $\nu$. This will give you your transition times, except you reject some of the with probability $1 - \nu_i/\nu$. The argument above shows why that gives the same transition rates as your original continuous time markov chain; that determines the description of the stochastic process uniquely so you have an alternative way to generate samples of the same stochastic process. Sorry I want to help but I'm not sure what else to say about this.

Comment: Oh, okey. So we pretend that when we are in state i, we are actually in a poisson process with rate $\nu$, and each time an event happens we either stay or leave the state. For a state j, the probability of leaving to state j is $\frac{\nu_i}{\nu}*P_{ij}$, so by the sampling argument for a Poisson process, this process of leaving to state j is also a poisson process, with parameter $\nu*\frac{\nu_i}{\nu}*P_{ij}$. [cont]

Comment: [cont]
This means that the waiting times will be exponentially distributed, and the parameter for the first real transition is $\Sigma_j v_i*P_{ij}=v_i$?, and the probability of it going to J is $\frac{v_i/v*P_{iJ}}{v_i/v}=P_{iJ}$, here I used properties for the minimum time when we have several exponential distributions(when adding the rates, and calculating the probability $P_{iJ}$). Do you agree with this argument? I see that your argument is simpler and better, but I would also like to understand it by using the poisson sampling theorem.

Comment: Yes youve almost got it. Except the new process isnt actually poisson due to the fact that the transition rates are not uniform.

Comment: Yes, but we pretend they are uintil the first real event has happened?, and that is why the calculations are "legal"?

Comment: The process with rate $\nu$ that includes the fake events is Poisson. The process of only "real" transotions is not Poisson. But the involved calculations "don't care" because your just computing one exponential waiting time at a time.

Comment: I meant that each j, the process of leaving to j from i can be thought of as Poisson processess by itself(so we get many processess simulatniously). But that only works uintil the first one has happened, and hence we must calculate the minimum time uintil the first of many poisson processes occur?, by using that the rate of the minimum of many exponential random varaibles, is the sum of their rates?

Comment: I guess, but since this only works for one event at a time its just a convoluted way of saying the waiting time is exponentially distributed.

Comment: Ah I understand, that was the only way I was able to use the poisson samling argument directly for showing that the fictitious one implies the real one. But your original argument is probably the best no matter what, it explains why they can do what they do.

Comment: Hello again Kai Sikorski. I found a property of the exponential distribution online, I am wondering if you agree that this proof of the original property might also be correct? According to http://www.statlect.com/ucdexp1.htm a distribution is expoenential if and only if $P(t<X +\le t+ \Delta t| X>t)=\lambda*\Delta t+o(\Delta t)$. So in our situation for the new process $P(t<Y \le t + \Delta t| Y>t)= (v*\Delta t+ o(\Delta t))*\frac{v_i}{v}=v_i*\Delta t +o(\Delta t)$, hence the new process must be exponential with parameter $v_i$?